# How to pass variable $data to controller?

Tags: codeigniter

I've no idea to pass `$data` variable from Model to Controller.
In Model:

```
function active(){

      $query = $this->db->query(" SELECT *  FROM `event` WHERE DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%m-%d-%Y' ) BETWEEN START AND END ");

      foreach($query->result_array() as $row){

            $ev_name = $row['ev_name']; 
            $image = $row['ev_image'];
            $start = $row['start'];
            $end = $row['end'];
            $desc = $row['ev_dec'];
            $ev_id  = $row['ev_id'];

      }


          $data = array('ev_name' =>  $ev_name,
                   'ev_image' => $image,
                    'start' => $start,
                    'end' =>  $end,
                    'ev_desc' =>$desc,
                     'ev_id'=> $ev_id
                   );

          echo $data;

       }
```

In Controller:

```
function active_event()
{

   $this->load->view('active_event');
   $this->load->model('Usermodel', Sdata);

}
```

Comment: Instead of echoing $data, why not **return** it. So instead of **echo $data** > **return $data**. One thing also, in your controller, best would be pre-load the model in the constructor **$this->load->model('Usermodel', 'myModel');**. You could then call a function in the model by **$this->myModel->active()**. To get the value returned(which is $data), **$data = $this->myModel->active()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `return` keyword which is used for passing data from one function to another. You also need to load and call model method before loading view so that you can use data from modal in view. I think you need to check [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [Codeigniter userguide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/).

In your model,

```
function active(){

  $query = $this->db->query(" SELECT *  FROM `event` WHERE DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%m-%d-%Y' ) BETWEEN START AND END ");

  foreach($query->result_array() as $row){

        $ev_name = $row['ev_name']; 
        $image = $row['ev_image'];
        $start = $row['start'];
        $end = $row['end'];
        $desc = $row['ev_dec'];
        $ev_id  = $row['ev_id'];

  }


      $data = array('ev_name' =>  $ev_name,
               'ev_image' => $image,
                'start' => $start,
                'end' =>  $end,
                'ev_desc' =>$desc,
                 'ev_id'=> $ev_id
               );

      return $data;

   }
```

In your controller,

```
function active_event()
{
   $this->load->model('YOUR MODEL NAME');
   $data = $this->YOURMODELNAME->active();
   $this->load->view('active_event', $data);

}
```